# Why does the following map function produce undefined objects?

Tags: javascript, loops

I have an array `context.buildingFields.finished` that looks like this:

```
[{ name: 'a' type: 'text', value: '1' }, { name: 'b' type: 'file', value: '2' }]
```

And I have a function that loops through that array to create a new one `context.createPanoramasPayload` with **only** the fields of type `file`:

```
function handleCreatePanoramas (uploadedPhoto, context, callback) {
    const panoramasFields = context.buildingFields.finished
    context.createPanoramasPayload = panoramasFields.map(field => {
      if (field.type !== 'file') return
      return {
        name: 'index',
        value: uploadedPhoto
      }
    })
    callback(context.createPanoramasPayload)
  }
}
```

I thought I would produce something like this (say with only one field of type `file`):

```
[{ name: 'b' type: 'file', value: '2' }]
```

However, what I'm getting is something like this:

```
[undefined, { name: 'b' type: 'file', value: '2' }]
```

Why is this? And how to modify the code to achieve what I want?

Comment: You are returning `undefined` in statement `if (field.type !== 'file') return`

Comment: you want `filter` and then `map`

Comment: `what I'm getting is something like this` - impossible ... you'd be getting `[undefined, {name: 'index', value: 'whatever uploadedPhoto is'}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` returns an array that has the same length as the given array. It does not help to `return` just like that, as that will generate an `undefined` value in your mapped array. Instead you need to apply `filter` first:

```
context.createPanoramasPayload = panoramasFields.filter(field => {
    return field.type === 'file';
}).map(field => {
    return {
        name: 'index',
        value: uploadedPhoto
    }
})
```

This keeps with a *functional* way of programming.

As a side note, since the callback functions now don't do anything else than return something, you can use the expression syntax for the arrow functions:

```
context.createPanoramasPayload = panoramasFields
    .filter(field => field.type === 'file')
    .map(field => ({
        name: 'index',
        value: uploadedPhoto
    }));
```

Comment: Thanks. Weird for some reason say if I upload 2 files the final array has 5.

Comment: you must be doing something very different in your actual code then - what is the content of your final array? (and the initial array)

Comment: I guess `reduce` is more suited in this case

Comment: never mind, I had another loop on top of this one ... thanks!

Comment: @Rajesh - `reduce` is good - single iteration - you should post an answer :p

Comment: @JaromandaX I have added it, but as an extension to this answer. Please feel free to update any inconsistency/missing information.

Answer (score 0):

You are using **map** function here, that means it will not reduce the length of the array. It return same length array. So use **filter**  to get result.

Comment: and map to map to the final result requirement - clearly you don't understand that filter doesn't map - oops, you removed that code :p

Answer (score 0):

This answer is an extension to @[trincot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5459839/trincot)'s answer.

Using `.filter` + `.map` is not wrong, but it adds to extra iterations. Both these functions have their own specific use-case but when you need to do both, `.reduce` is more suited as you can manually parse object and return custom *array/object*.

**Sample**

```js
context.createPanoramasPayload = panoramasFields.reduce(function(p, c) {
  if (c.type === 'file')
    p.push({
      name: 'index',
      value: uploadedPhoto
    });
  return p;
}, [])
```

Also note the use of *anonymous function* instead of *arrow function*(`=>`).

What arrow function does is it binds current context to the passed callback function, so that we can use `this` inside the callback. If you are using arrow function but not using `this` inside callback, you are wasting the efforts engine puts in binding context to the callback. For this reason, if you do not use `this`, in my understanding, its better to use anonymous function instead of arrow function.

Though its not wrong, but in my POV, it is a bad practice.

Comment: Your comments on arrow functions are ill-informed. What extra work do you think you are asking the engine to do exactly?

Comment: @torazaburo we are asking engine to bind the current context to the callback so that we can access `this` inside callback as well. In my understanding this is an overkill. I'll update the explanation though.

Comment: @torazaburo thanks for pointing it out. I have updated the answer. Also it is just my POV, so if there is any inconsistencies in my understanding, please feel free to point it out

Comment: A quick performance test shows no difference whatsoever between anonymous functions and arrow functions.